# Axios - Should I 'type assert' the returned data if I'm already declaring the function return type?

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, axios

Having the following piece of code:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
async function fetchAPI<T>(path: string, data: any): Promise<T> {
  return (await axios.get(path, data)).data as T
}

async function getSomething(): Promise<SomeType> {
  return await fetchAPI<SomeType>("https://example.com", {data: 123})
}
```

I believe that the type assertion `as T` in `fetchAPI()` is unnecessary as I'm already stating that the function will return data of the type `T`, but I'm not sure of that.
Am I correct?

Comment: The compiler will tell you if it was necessary if you remove it.

Comment: Hi @H.B., thank you for your reply. I believe my doubt is more theoretical than practical about the typescript rules of type assertion and return types.

Comment: Indeed, my compiler is not complaining at all about this piece of code, but I'm trying to understand the underlying mechanisms of type assertion so that I can omit this mentioned assertion in the future.

Comment: Just a side note: There's no need for `getSomething` to be `async`, it can be just `return fetchAPI<SomeType>(/*...*/);` `return await` at the top level of a function doesn't do anything useful. (It *does* inside a `try`/`catch` or similar.)

Comment: Indeed! In the case of `fetchAPI` I actually need the await so I can extract the `data` object from it. But in getSomething I really don't need it. It is more an assurance that no one will try to return a non-promisified value there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data type of `.data` is `any`, you can return it from your function without the type assertion. So whether you include the assertion is a matter of style. You actually have at least four style options:

1. Keep what you have (both the type assertion and the return type annotation)
2. Remove the type assertion (because it will happen anyway thanks to the return type annotation)
3. Remove the return type annotation (because the TypeScript compiler will infer the type from the `return`)
4. `axios.get` is generic, you could provide `T` as the type argument:

   ```
   return (await axios.get<T>(path, data)).data;
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^
   ```

(#4 can be used with or without the return type annotation.)

But it is a matter of style.

One argument for including the type assertion or `axios.get` type argument could be that it tells people reading the code later exactly where the `T` value being returned comes from. It's obvious in your example because it's a nice short function, but it can be less obvious in more complex functions. But reasonable people can disagree about whether that's useful.

Comment: <subjective> FWIW, for me #4 is the winner. :-) (With or without the return type annotation, depending on the size of the function.) </subjective>

Comment: It is a small function, the origin of the returned data is very explicit, but I like the idea of showing exactly where that typed data is originated. And our project's linter doesn't allow functions without a return type, so I'm going with #4 with return type annotation heheh. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In general, it depends on whether the type of the object that is returned is *compatible* with the return type of the function. So depending on how an API/function is designed you may or may not need any assertions.

Some general examples:

```
// Returns data as `any` which is compatible with everything
async function getData1(url: string): Promise<{ data: any }> {
    return { data: {} };
}

async function fetchAPI1<T>(path: string): Promise<T> {
  return (await getData1(path)).data // `any` is compatible with `T`
}

// Requires caller to specify type or get `unknown`
async function getData2<T = unknown>(url: string): Promise<{ data: T }> {
    return { data: {} as any as T };
}

async function fetchAPI2_1<T>(path: string): Promise<T> {
  return (await getData2(path)).data as T // `unknown` asserted to be T
}

async function fetchAPI2_2<T>(path: string): Promise<T> {
  return (await getData2<T>(path)).data // Assertion happens inside `getData2`
}
```